# Is $|S|=|S\cup \mathbb{N}|$ always true if $S$ is an infinite set disjoint from $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: set-theory

Prove or disprove: Let $S$ be an infinite set such that, $S\cap \mathbb{N}=\emptyset$. Is$|S|=|S\cup \mathbb{N}|$ always true?

Comment: What's $\varphi$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: they are disjoint sets @Gae.S.

Comment: See [$X$ is infinite and $Y$ at most countable. Why is $\lvert X \rvert = \lvert X \cup Y \rvert$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155237/x-is-infinite-and-y-at-most-countable-why-is-lvert-x-rvert-lvert-x-c). I think this holds without the condition that $S$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\Bbb N$ is the smallest infinite set, in the sense that
$$
\text{$X$ infinite}\Longrightarrow|\Bbb N|\leq|X|.
$$
Thus, if $S$ is infinite one has $|S|=|S\cup\Bbb N|$ regardless if $S$ and $\Bbb N$ are disjoint or not.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. How does $|S|=|S\cup\mathbb N|$ follow from the fact that $|\mathbb N|$ is the smallest infinite cardinality?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: because is a general fact (which I assumed known) that if $A$ and $B$ are sets with $B$ infinite and $|A|\leq|B|$ then $|A\cup B|=|B|$.